# Issue in Dynamic Job creation in Talend

Tags: talend, talend-mdm

I got the requirement like this,
Create a single Talend job with reads multiple tables and writes to multiple files dynamically(when we give a tablename via context variable the job should take that table as `select * from tablename` and writes to file tablename.txt)

My oracle query given in toracle input stage-

```
"SELECT *  FROM '"+context.Table_Name+"'"
```

In Context Variable part given as

```
Table_Name-    String-   checked Prompt for value for dynamic table name
```

In the metadata definition for Oracle table I gave as

```
Type="dynamic" db type="varchar2"
```

Issues Facing:

1. The context variable is not been identified by the job

   ```
   ORA-00903: invalid table name
   Exception in component tOracleInput_1
   java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00903: invalid table name

   at oracle.jdbc.driver.SQLStateMapping.newSQLException(SQLStateMapping.java:91)
   at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.newSQLException(DatabaseError.java:112)
   at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:173)
   ```

   But when I hard code the tablename, job is running fine
2. The target file path I gave as

   ```
   "C:/Talend/OutputFIles/context.Table_Name.txt"
   ```

Instead of printing value of context variable, I am getting as `context.Table_Name.txt` as filename!!!

Please help me on this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try to remove ' around the table name?
Try this:

`"SELECT * FROM " + context.Table_Name`

Same for filename construction, you should write:

`"C:/Talend/OutputFIles/" + context.Table_Name + ".txt"`

Better, you should have pathname defined by a context variable, giving:
`context.OutputPath + context.Table_Name + ".txt"`
TRF

Comment: You are awsome!!Complete stuff worked!! Thanks a lot again!!:)